# Insert values in mySQL using wcf REST and Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

I wrote a REST web service in C#. Get request works fine, but insert, update and delete not.
When I try to insert some values from an Android tablet (client) via the REST service into a mySQL database an error occurs:  Method not allowed

I send a JSON string from the android client to the web service:

in Android Developer Tool (eclipse):

```
String url = IP + PORT +"/RESTService/insert/";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                json.put("userName", name);
                json.put("userPassword", password);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);
```

in C#:
Service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/insert/{jsonObj}", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,       
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void InsertUser(string jsonObj);
```

Service methode:

```
 public void InsertUser(string jsonObj)
    {
        string name = null;
        string password = null;
        DataContractJsonSerializer obj = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(User));
        dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObj);

        foreach (var data in dynObj.userObject)
        {
            name = data.userName;
            password = data.userPassword;
        }

       string sql = "INSERT INTO user (userName, userPassword) VALUES('" + name + "', '" + password +"';)";

       if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
           conn.Open();
       }

       command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn.Close();
       command.Dispose();
    }
```

My User:

```
    namespace RESTService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string userPassword { get; set; }

        public User(string name, string password)
        {
            this.userName = name;
            this.userPassword = password;
        }
    }
```

When I start the web service and try to insert the values via android app, nothing happens. I think, that the values from the app don't reach the web service. But I have no idea why.
It would be great, if somebody can help me :).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to write a C# unit test that exercises the InsertUser method through the web service. When running this test I think you'd discover that your UriTemplate is incorrect. If you're making a POST, the json object will be in the body of the request, not in the url. I'd try an attribute like this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/users", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,       
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json]
```

Your android url would look like this (I think):

```
String url = IP + PORT + "/users";
```

Another thing to check out would be Fiddler. When your unit test passes, you can inspect  successful requests. Your [android client can also be configured](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) to use Fiddler.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I'll try the C# unit test.
But I have some questions, in my request body, my user is transmitted as followed:
{"userPassword":"test","userName":"testname"}

How can I get the attributes userName and userPassword with their values. What kind of parameter(string, object,...), in my web service methode insert should I use

public void InsertUser(string jsonObj) or

public void InsertUser(object jsonObj)

to convert the JSONString to my User object?

Comment: You should be able to change your web service signature to this:  `public void InsertUser(User user)` WCF will take care of deserialization of the User automatically.

Comment: perfect, now it works ;). Thanks a lot for the service signature tip.
I changed my method to:
`public void InsertUser(User user){string name = user.userName; string password = user.userPassword; ...}`