# WCF Web json Services from database ? error in Reading value

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, wcf

I am developing a Restful Web Services using `.net(WCF)`.
I followed [this link,](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm)

But here at the Starting part in WCF test Client at `GetData()`
when I Enter the Value 13 or 3 its taking and I pressed invoke

But at the URL I am getting No Data..
Actual result:

[image]

Till `Service1.svc` its Fine But the Value at Get Data  should be like below
Expected Result:

[image]

But Its not working

I don't what is the problem, Here I am Using VS-2012 Premium.

Comment: use mentioned link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613097/WCF-RESTful-services-and-consuming-them-in-an-HTML

Comment: Its Ok @DhavalPatel Sir But here after creating WCF restful web services I need to Integrate it with MySQL Data base actually in the mentioned link its SQL server But I need to add MySQL connection, and what ever in the Database it should be display as JSON. any Help sir,..

Comment: I am not getting about the database which you were trying to co-relate with WCF service.

Comment: ok Sir But after this I need to integrate with data base in your example link its available sir,.. Please Help

Comment: you can integrate with any database WCF service part is not dependant with any database.

Comment: sorry to ask this sir, this is final is any example which reads database and display them as json in the part of Restful web services, I am trying since past weeks,. you can check my previous questions,..That too in MySQL,..

Comment: The following post my help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870805/insert-values-in-mysql-using-wcf-rest-and-android

Comment: what about that link in My Post.... why its not working....

Comment: Is GetData being hit if a breakpoint is added to it?  I would recommend you enable trace logging on your WCF.  You can do that in the web.config.  This will allow you to see if there are any uncaught exceptions.  Another thing to try would be Fiddler, this way you can examine your network traffic to determine if the request is even making it to the WCF.

Comment: Yes @alan sir,. I Tried But I don't know what is the problem that already done Example is not working Once Possible check that link and try it sir is that example is working or is there any problem on my side,..

Answer (score 0):

In example there is "getData/{value}" not "GetData/{value}", not sure but it can be case sensitive.
You also can change UriTemplate to "getData/?value={value}", and call it "getData/?value=13"

Comment: its ok sir its working fine thank you i solved this in this i need to Build with Vs2010 with .net 3.5 frame work its worked fine,,,